# How to set correct time with AM PM with Calendar object?

Tags: java, calendar

Simple question why the result is like the following for this code:

```java
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
cal2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
System.out.println(cal2.getTime().toString()); // Wed Jan 13 00:11:08 EET 2021
cal2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
System.out.println(cal2.getTime().toString()); // Wed Jan 13 12:11:08 EET 2021
        
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString()); // Tue Jan 12 12:11:08 EET 2021
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString()); // Tue Jan 12 00:11:08 EET 2021
```

The first looks like it is 12 at midnight not afternoon.
The third one looks like it is 12 afternoon, not midnight

Why setting calendar AM or PM multiple times change the result?
How to set the time correctly?

Comment: **Don't use `Calendar`**. It's obsolete for a long time. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalTime`, `ZonedDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calendar is *very confusing*

You are so far from the first being confused about how the `Calendar` class works. Fortunately the class is also long outdated. You should not use it.

> Why setting calendar AM or PM multiple times change the result? …

To answer your question as asked, Andi80 is correct in the other answer and the comments to it: `HOUR` goes from 0 through 11. The documentation says about `HOUR`:

> Field number for `get` and `set` indicating the hour of the morning or
> afternoon. `HOUR` is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and
> midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the
> `HOUR` is 10.

When you first set hour to 12 and AM/PM to PM, one should have expected an exception because the hour value is out of range. But no, a `Calendar` object with default settings doesn’t give you that. Instead it sets the time to 0 AM the following day; Jan 13 when you ran the code on Jan 12. By `Calendar` logic hour 12 is the hour that comes after hour 11.

When you set PM *again*, `Calendar` takes off from the time you had already got, which is in AM, and changes it into PM, so you get 12:11:08, still on Jan 13, the following day.

Why does it calculate the time twice? Not once and not three times when you do three calls to `set()`? It’s another confusing trait of `Calendar`. It calculates the time when you call `getTime()` (and some designated other methods). At that point it picks up all the changes from the calls to `set()` up to that point and combines them to the best of its abilities, discarding some if there are conflicts, using rules that no person in their right mind will want to understand.

The case for AM is similar, so I leave the details to the reader.

### java.time

> … How to set the time correctly?

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work. If you just want 12 noon or 12 midnight, they are built in as constants:

```
    LocalTime t12Noon = LocalTime.NOON;
    System.out.println(t12Noon);
    
    LocalTime t12Midnight = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
    System.out.println(t12Midnight);
```

Output is:

> ```
> 12:00
> 00:00
> ```

A `LocalTime` is a time of day without a date.

If you have already got a time and only want to adjust the hour and AM/PM, use `with()`:

```
    LocalTime t12Noon = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .with(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 12)
            .with(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, 1); // 1 = PM
    System.out.println(t12Noon);
    
    LocalTime t12Midnight = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .with(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 12)
            .with(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, 0); // 0 = AM
    System.out.println(t12Midnight);
```

> ```
> 12:47:00.665155
> 00:47:00.669248
> ```

If you need the date too, use `ZonedDateTime` or another appropriate class. All of the date-time classes of java.time that include time of day have the same `with` method, so the code will be the same.

If you indispensably need a `Calendar` object for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now, use a `ZonedDateTIme` from java.time for your time math. Then use `GregorianCalendar.from(ZoendDateTIme)` for the conversion to a `Calendar` object.

### Links

- [Documentation of `Calendar.HOUR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.HOUR takes inputs in range 0-11. It will wrap around the 12 to a 0.

Use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY instead to use values from 0-23.

Comment: ok, why the result changed when call set method again?

Comment: The Calendar class does not actually calculate the time until you call the getTime() method (or any of the other getters). It will initially only keep a flag isTimeSet as false. During the first execution of a getter, it will calculate the time and setTimeSet to true. Here it probably overrides the value that was set for the AM_PM field because the hour of 12 is wrapped to 0.


12 PM -> Wraps hour to 0 AM (because hour should be in range 0-11)

Comment: How does this answer why setting the field with `Calendar.AM` twice, sets it to `Calendar.PM` the first time? And vice versa. It seems to be inconsistent in well.. consistently getting it wrong the first time.

Comment: The Calendar is initially set to Hour = 12, PM_AM = PM. The calculation in the getTime() method changes this to "0 AM" because of limit for the hour field. That's why 0 AM (midnight) is returned in the first print statement.
Afterwards, the second call to set(Calendar.AM_PM, PM) changes the value to "0 PM" which is the afternoon.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps elaborate this a little in your Answer? I tried setting it to `24*7+12` and it sets it to midday a week from now, so you're clearly right that it wraps it around :)